# how to forward the url query parameter access token when using auth forward in traefik

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, traefik

I am using traefik auth forward to do some authorize, this is the middleware configure look like:

```
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: jwt-token-auth
  namespace: reddwarf-pro
spec:
  forwardAuth:
    address: >-
      http://dolphin-post-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local:11014/post/auth/access_token/verify
```

everything works fine, but now I found the auth forward did not forward the query parameters because when I connect the websocket, I put the token in query parameters. so as the sse connection(the sse https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events did not support the custom header to put the access token). but I could not get the access token from parameters in the verify function. This is how I defined the verify function:

```
@GetMapping("/access_token/verify")
ResponseEntity verifyAccessToken(@RequestParam(value = "access_token",required = false) String accessToken, @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization",required = false) String authorizationHeader);
```

what should I do to make the traefik auth forward to pass the access token? any suggestions? this is how I pass the access token in url:

```
curl https://tex.demo.top/tex/project/compile/log/stream\?project_id\=287ea73d1c78463298e9e5b267cab87f\&file_name\=main.tex\&version_no\=c880ee90933b46d19b16bef9f7736658\&qid\=350\&access_token\=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEwMywiZGV2aWNlSWQiOiiuwIyOTQ1ZGUwN2NkM2I1N2FkNmNkNTk4YjdhZTFjZTlmdoMCIsImFwcElkIjoibjI5UGEyOVdTMSIsImx0IjoxLCJldCI6MCwicGlkIjoxMywiZXhwIjoxNjk1Mzc2Mzkyf.WA8_XuKDd9927_j8bgjKNem7Z0WuS323DTz0DPlX_TurkZm4m7CKaerFAfN8jyM5t86MMHdtXp9N8P4ChmpQ
```

Comment: **Try passing authentication parameters in query string :** When using OAuth, you can often also send your access token in a query string instead of in an authorization header, so try something like: `GET `[`https://www.example.com/api/v1/users/1?access\\\_token=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCD`](https://www.example.com/api/v1/users/1?access_token=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCD)

Comment: I already do it like that, but the auth forwad did not forward the query parameters to the auth api.

Answer (score 1):

fisrt step enable the trustForwardHeader in traefik(2.10.x) middleware:

```
trustForwardHeader: true
```

then get the uri on the server side verify method like this(Java Spring Boot):

```
String uri = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Uri");
```